# Powershell datatype incompatiablity

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Powershell scrip that reads the name of a database from a table in SQL. There is only one column in the table. Which then passes the name of the database in the array, to the dbatools backup command in the name field. The next line should add the database to the secondary.

```
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "serverA" -database "someTable" -query "select * from dbo.Table1"

foreach ($item in $results) {

      Backup-DbaDatabase -sqlinstance serverA -path Z:\SQL.Backups -database $item
      Add-DbaAgDatabase -sqlinstance uw2-sql-tpr-003 -AvailabilityGroup tirepower_ag -database $item   }
```

However, when I execute the code, I get an error:

> WARNING: [13:01:53][Backup-DbaDatabase] No databases match the request
>   for backups

The only reason I can find is, instead of a string that $item variable is passing a datarow which the dbatools commands do not understand.

I'm sure there's an easy answer to this that I am not seeing, but how do I convert the $item to a string for the dbatools commands to take?

Comment: I'm not sure of the properties of $Item but something like ```$Item.toString()``` or ```$Item.name```

Comment: `Invoke-Sqlcmd` outputs [Formatted table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#outputs). I'd start analyzing `foreach ($item in $results) {$item;"$item";$item.GetType()}`…

Comment: Thank you both. Brian had the answer, and JosefZ pointed me towards a deeper understanding.